# Question about Working with Lists / Tables

Tags: manipulate, list-manipulation, slider

I have a data point set embedded in a manipulate. dtpts1a={{X,Y},{X,Y},{X,Y},{X,Y},{X,Y},{X,Y},{X,Y}, and so on and so forth, continuing}
How do I alter, how do I change the magnitude of each dependent variable (Y)? I would like to multiply each Y value, all at the same time, with some kind of a function under the control of a slider bar. Like this, {{X,0.5*Y},{X,0.5*Y},{X,0.5*Y}}} or possibly, {{X,2*Y},{X,2*Y}},{X,2*Y}}}. Ideas? Suggestions?

Comment: you could write it as  `dtpts1a={{X,n*Y},{X,n*Y},{X,n*Y}...` and then have slider for `n` to change it.

Comment: Yes, that would work. But I'm hoping for something easier. My data set sums to 128 point pairs {{X,Y}}

Comment: You can use Nasser's solution with `MapAt[n*#&, dtpts1a, {All,2}]`

Comment: You could use a dot product: ``dtpts1a.{{1, 0}, {0, .5}}``

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
dtpts1a = Table[RandomInteger[{1,100}],{i,128},{j,2}];

Manipulate[
    MapAt[n*#&, dtpts1a, {All,2}]
,{n,0,1}]
```

**EDIT**

By default `Manipulate` uses steps of `10^-3 * rangeMax` for the variable. You can decrease the step size and use `SetAccuracy` to always show four digits

```
Manipulate[
    SetAccuracy[MapAt[n*#&, dtpts1a, {All,2}],5]
,{n,0,1,0.0001}]
```

Comment: Mister Hausdorff's solution works. dtpts1c=MapAt[n*# &, dtpts1a,{All, 2}]; One last question. How do I "SetPrecision" for the output? I am wanting four significant figures for each one of my calculated dependent variables. Thanks in advance. OKCarl

Comment: I just edited my answer